# How to select a tag via href in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've already search about it. But it is not the same as the other's problem. What I want is to select a `<a>` tag using `href` attribute. Please see my code below:

```
<div class="jump-to">
   <ul>
     <li>No a</li>
     <li class="with-a">
        <a href="hello1">Has a</a>
     </li>
     <li class="with-a">
        <a href="hello8">Has a</a>
     </li>
     <li class="with-a">
        <a href="hello10">Has a</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

```js
var current_anchor = window.location.href;
var left_anchor = $(".jump-to ul li.with-a a[href="+ current_anchor +"]").prev("li a").attr("href");

alert(left_anchor);
```

Comment: What does `current_anchor ` refers to

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selection via the `href` attribute is working fine. The problem is because your DOM traversal is incorrect.

`prev('li a')` is not valid from the `a` as the `li` is not a sibling. You need to first use `closest('li')` to get the parent, then `prev()`, then `find('a')`, like this:

```js
var current_anchor = 'http://localhost/myproject/hello8';
var left_anchor = $('.jump-to ul li.with-a a[href="' + current_anchor + '"]').closest('li').prev('li').find('a').attr('href');
console.log(left_anchor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jump-to">
  <ul>
    <li>No a</li>
    <li class="with-a">
      <a href="http://localhost/myproject/hello1">Has a</a>
    </li>
    <li class="with-a">
      <a href="http://localhost/myproject/hello8">Has a</a>
    </li>
    <li class="with-a">
      <a href="http://localhost/myproject/hello10">Has a</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add one more list item as I've updated the code above?

Comment: Sure, although it makes no difference to the JS logic at all

Comment: It returns an error for me, `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .jump-to ul li.with-a a[href=hello8]`

Comment: That selector is fine and you can see it works fine in the example. Are you certain that `$` is referring to jQuery in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I just copied your code. Is it work with other `url`s? e.g. `http://localhost/myproject/hello8` ?

Comment: Oh, maybe that's why it is not working. But what if I want to select using the FULL url?

Comment: If you're working with a full URL you need to wrap the attribute value in quotes. I updated the answer to show you how

Comment: Haah! it's working now. That's great!  But one more thing, what's the difference bet. the one that has `'` and has no quotes?

Comment: There's no logical difference between `'` and `"`, but the former makes it easier to wrap attributes in a selector string or HTML with `"`